# Is it possible to unfold a variadic (lambda) template and the pass those functions return value to another variadic function?

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, unfold

So I wonder given a variadic template function like following:

```cpp
template<typename...Fs>
parse(int x, Fs...funcs);
```

Where we ensure (through C++20 concept) that is convertible to `std::function<double(int)>`. Could we use unfold it into another functions argument, like passing to following one:

```cpp
template<typename...Ts>
test(Ts...args);
```

Where again we ensure all `Ts` is and must be able to convert`double`.

What is expecting is, suppose `a`, `b`, `c` are lambda expressions, calling `parse(12, a, b, c)` is equivalent to calling `test(a(12), b(12), c(12))`.

---

Something I tried is like following

```cpp
template<typename...Fs>
parse(int x, Fs...func) {
    return test(..., funcs(x));
}
```

But didn't work. It seems like that most unfolding expression examples puts a function within the expression, so does this means unfold expression by itself can't return as a list of arguments. Instead, perhaps it could only return as single value?

If so, is there any workaround like first construct it into an array like `(..., void(arr[i++]=args))`, but I couldn't find ways to expand it back to argument pack. (I would want to expand arguments back to argument pack as I want to reuse other functions within my library instead of writing another one that takes either array or initializer list as argument.)

Comment: Just `test(funcs(x)...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax would be:

```
template <typename... Fs>
auto parse(int x, Fs... func)
{
    return test(funcs(x)...);
}
```